# Meteor weird happening : blank screen on ui

Tags: meteor

I can see the app in dev environment. But when i deploy in PROD, bundling the code i see a blank screen.

I start off again with a fresh project.. then i am able to deploy the code.. and see the ui in PROD.

But after putting down some more code .. the screen again turns blank ..

i am using `iron-router`, `accounts*`, `accouns-ui-bootstrap-3` ,jquery ,underscore and less with 0.6.6.3 version of meteor.

Anyone facing similar issues. I have spent the entire day trying to fix up the issue.

Comment: What happens if you run in dev mode with `meteor --production`?

Comment: Weird nothing is shown on UI. Same as prod. But works fine with meteor/mrt

Comment: How to fix this up,, how to figure out what is the issue ?

Comment: Do you get anything in the javascript console as errors?

Comment: yeah ! i see few errors :(   .. thanks i will check the code on my side.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: AccountsEntry is not defined 6a14468d6b01e96e33589bc57e9512cf924f51e0.js:14
Uncaught Error: Oh no! No route found for path: "/"

Comment: It looks like you have two problems. One is you don't have a homepage defined in your router. The second is you have a collection called `AccountsEntry` but you've variable scoped it (change `var AccountsEntry =..` to `AccountsEntry = ..`)

Comment: Because in dev mode the homepage is displayed and since the errors are in a different file they don't interrupt anything. In production mode the file is concatenated & minified for speed. So if there is a single error in your syntax somewhere the whole app wont work. You have to make sure you've set it up correctly before you bundle up.

Comment: Its like this line `vaxasjk; alert ("OK");`. the alert won't run because of the syntax error before it. So you have this AccountsEntry error which stops the rest of the script and you haven't defined a homepage in your router which is why you get a blank page.

Comment: thanks, there was issue in one of the package that i was using. Fixed that!